# If $G$ is a group and $a,b \in G $, then: $ |\langle a,b \rangle|=|\langle a\rangle|\cdot |\langle b\rangle| \ \Longleftrightarrow a=b$?

Tags: group-theory

Such that $\langle a\rangle , \langle a,b\rangle $ is a subgroups of $G$ generated by $\lbrace a\rbrace, \lbrace a,b\rbrace $ respectively and $| \ . |$ is the member of $\langle a\rangle $ element.(Cardinal). May be for finite group is true bout for infinity:
If $G=(\mathbb{R},+)$, $a=\dfrac{1}{2}, b=1$ then $\lbrace 1\rangle =\mathbb{Z}$ and $\langle \dfrac{1}{2}\rangle =W=\langle 1,\dfrac{1}{2}\rangle $.
Then:
$$\aleph_{0}=\aleph^{2}_{0} $$
bout: $$1\neq \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: $\langle\frac{1}{2}\rangle \neq \mathbb{Q}$. For example, $\frac{1}{3} \not\in \langle\frac{1}{2}\rangle$.

Comment: It is certainly not true in the finite case, for if $a=b$ then $\langle a,b\rangle=\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$ and $|\langle a,b\rangle|=|\langle a\rangle||\langle b\rangle|$ can only hold if $a=b=1$

Comment: @Hagen well, $a=b={\rm id}_G$... or $|a|=|b|=1$.

Comment: For finite if $|<a,b>|=|<a>|.|<b>|$ then $a=b$?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: btw it's \langle and \rangle for $\langle$ and $\rangle$

Comment: I think its true.

Comment: Do you possibly mean to square the left hand?  As several commenters have pointed out, the statement is false is written.

Comment: Mind you, the statement is false even if you square the left hand.  Take the non-cyclic group of order 4 and let a and b be distinct elements of order 2.

Answer (score 2):

No, if a group of order $5$ is generated by an element $a$, then $G = <a,a>$, but $|<a>|\cdot|<a>| = 25 \neq |<a,a>| = 5$. This is a clear counterexample

Comment: You can not assumed $a=b$.

Comment: Why not? This is exactly what your question asks. If $a=b$ but it does not follow that $|\langle a,b \rangle| = |\langle a \rangle | \cdot | \langle b \rangle |$ then it cannot be true the if and only if implication.

Comment: @JamalFarokhi Really, how many examples did you check to arrive at your hypothesis in the first place?